# ExtJS One-Dimensional Array combobox

Tags: arrays, extjs, combobox, dimension

I want to use a one dimensional array as the store for a combobox. It knows how many elements are in the array. But the list is filled with rows of blank text.

```
Ext.getCmp('variablesAttributesPanel').add(
  {
     xtype: 'combo', 
     id: variables[j].getTitle() + 'ValuesCombo', 
     store: variables[j].values
  });
```

variables[j].values is the array that I would like to use. Whenever I try to use a store, it doesn't populate anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ExtJS are you using?

This is the link to combo box documentation for ExtJS 4. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox

First of all, "valueField" is a required config field for Combobox.

Secondly, you need to make sure your "variable[j]" is indeed a "Ext.data.Store" instance.